# Application of integrals (energy/work)

Tags: integration

I'm not sure about the integral associated with the example below. I see different options and I don't know exactly which one is the right one. My found options are the following:

$$ \int_{0}^{100} (1000+60x)*10*4 \,dx $$ or $$ \int_{0}^{400} (1000+60x)*10 \,dx $$

I'm not sure about my limits. Maybe it should be a maximum of 99 in stead of 100?

I also doubt whether my integral takes into account the fact that passengers only board from floor 1. Is it correct that my integral assumes that passengers board from floor 0? If so, how can I adjust this?

**The question:**

The Petronas Twin Towers is a skyscraper in Kuala Lumpur. In the ground floor entrance hall there is a mega-sized elevator with a weight of 1000  that can transport visitors from the ground floor (floor 0) to floor 100. Each floor is 4 meters high.

We are looking at a situation in which the elevator will travel from the ground floor (floor 0) to floor 100. On floor 1, the first person (weighing 60 ) steps into the elevator. An additional person weighing 60  then boards on each floor. In summary: From floor 1 there is 1 person going up, from floor 2 there are 2 people in the elevator, from floor 3 there are 3 people in the elevator, etc. Upon arrival at the 100th floor, there are 99 people in the elevator.

Calculate using integrals how much energy is consumed when the elevator reaches the top floor. Note: You may round the gravitational acceleration =9.8 /^2 to 10 /^2.

Comment: This is a repost ofcourse, since I answered the exact same questions today, published by you.

Comment: Hello, I have revised the question as it was unclear. I think your answer was not applied to integrals.

Comment: You seem not to understand how integration works, I'd recommend reading a book, There is a difference in discrete sums and continuos ones, by your definition $$\sum_a^{b} v = \int_a^b v dv$$

Answer (score 1):

Since the weights change in discrete periods, I would use a summation and not an integral.

$\sum_\limits{n=0}^{99} (1000 + 60n)(4\text{ meters})(10 \frac {\text {meters}}{\text {seconds}^2})$

$[(10^5) + (60)(\frac {(99)(100)}{2})] (40 \text{Nm})$

Nonetheless, the setup for the integral vs. the summation is identical.

What is the difference between:

$\int_{0}^{100} (1000 + 60x)(40)\ dx$ and $\int_{0}^{400} (1000 + 60x)(10)\ dx$?

The second integral would indicate that the mass increases 60 kilos per meter that the elevator moves vs. 60 kg per floor.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Why does your summation run from 0-99 and your integral run from 0-100? Could you also tell me what the integral looks like when a person already boards on floor 0?

Comment: @WinstonCherf - the summation is one for each individual floor, so 0 to 99 gives you 100 floors, and nothing happens at floor 100.  However, on an integral, you are continually adding all through the interval, so there is no "right before 100".

Comment: If we partition the interval [0,100] into 100 partitions and count the left side of each partition what is the index of the first and the last partition.  We could have partitioned from 1,100 but then that would require a small change to the summand.

Comment: In other words, nothing happens *when you get to 100*.  However, the number before 100 is 99.  In the continuous case, there isn't a clear, single value prior to 100, and it is infinitely close to 100 anyway (so it doesn't actually affect the calculation to include 100 itself).

Answer (score 0):

Integral is continuous, whilst $\sum$ is discrete.
You don't want $1.00000000000000000001$ passengers on the lift do you?